# What is the best Linux version to run on virtual box?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I just started learning Linux administration and i need to practice lessons i learnt on a Linux machine. I have a Windows PC and therefore i thought of running Linux on Virtual Box. Anyone who has experience using Virtual Box please help me to choose the best Linux Distro which i will be able to run smoothly on Virtual Box and which will also help me to practice my Linux admin lessons.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question should be moved to SuperUser in my eyes.
Responding to it, I would like to state that there is no "best" Linux distribution for practicing inside a virtual machine.

However, there are some combinations of Linux distros + desktop environments which perform really bad in a virtual environment, especially within a VirtualBox sandbox.
For example I found Ubuntu 12.04 + Unity to perform really bad within a VirtualBox container, even with 2D sessions switched on.
Also Linux Mint 12/13 showed some problems because of some menu effects.

Based on my own experience, I recommend running a distro you feel comfortable with (e.g. Ubuntu, Debian, Fedora..) in combination with a smooth desktop environment (KDE 3, Gnome 2..).

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a question that can't really be answered canonically, as it is asking for an opinion, so it may get downvoted or closed.

Second, if you're working somewhere that is using Linux, use whatever they're using. Just about any modern linux disro should work in Virtual Box.

Third, run a variety of them if you're interested in learning. Do the same thing (create a web server, for example) with Ubuntu, CentoOS, Debian...then note their differences.